# Copy bolds and unbolds with slider transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, so my website slider (which is using Owl Carousel) is causing the text on my site to either add/subtract weight. When it transitions, the text appears thin, and when it is done transitioning (sitting on a single image), it goes back to the correct boldness.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="lead-slider" class="owl-carousel oc-lead">
 <div class="lead-slide"></div>
 <div class="slide2"></div>
 <div class="slide3"></div>
 <div class="slide4"></div>
 <div class="slide5"></div>
 <div class="slide6"></div>
 <div class="slide7"></div>
 <div class="slide8"></div>
</div><!-- END OWL CAROUSEL -->
```

Now, these slides must be set to be the height of the window or viewport, so here is the associated Javascript function pertaining to that:

```
$("#lead-slider").height($(window).height() ) ;

$(window).resize(function(){
$("#lead-slider").height($(window).height() );

$(".lead-slide").height($(window).height() ) ;

$(window).resize(function(){
$(".lead-slide").height($(window).height() );

});

$(".slide2").height($(window).height() ) ;

$(window).resize(function(){
$(".slide2").height($(window).height() );

});

$(".slide3").height($(window).height() ) ;

$(window).resize(function(){
$(".slide3").height($(window).height() );

});

$(".slide4").height($(window).height() ) ;

$(window).resize(function(){
$(".slide4").height($(window).height() );

});

$(".slide5").height($(window).height() ) ;

$(window).resize(function(){
$(".slide5").height($(window).height() );

});

$(".slide6").height($(window).height() ) ;

$(window).resize(function(){
$(".slide6").height($(window).height() );

});

$(".slide7").height($(window).height() ) ;

$(window).resize(function(){
$(".slide7").height($(window).height() );

});

$(".slide8").height($(window).height() ) ;

$(window).resize(function(){
$(".slide8").height($(window).height() );

});
```

the JS for initializing the slider is as follows:

```
$("#lead-slider").owlCarousel({

  autoPlay: 3000,

  navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
  slideSpeed : 500,
  paginationSpeed : 400,
  singleItem:true,
  autoHeight : false

  });
```

Important notes: These images are actually background elements of divs (.lead-slide, .slide2, etc), like so:

```
.lead-slide {
background-image: url('../img/what-slide.jpg');
background-position: center bottom;
background-size: cover;
}
```

So I have tried messing with the Owl Carousel JS options to no avail. I've tried changing the CSS background-size. My guess is that the window.height may be to blame here, but not sure why. Seems that no matter what I try, the text seems to be either bolded or unbolded on the site. Very last thing, a link to a demo of what's going on:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpHMTvJiJhY&feature=youtu.be

Any ideas, guys? Much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need all that code repetition for slide-n etc, you can just use this selector `#lead-slider div`

Comment: Right on Nick, will add that change! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a webkit rendering issue.
Try to add the following css code to the page body.

CSS:

```
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```